# How to zoom using CTRL+Wheel in Visual studio 2022?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I used to use CTRL + Wheel to zoom in or out in previous version of Visual Studio.

I moved to the latest release (2022), but this feature has disappeared.

I tried to reset the keyboard scheme, but it still only scrolls when using the wheel.

How to restore/enable this behavior?

Comment: Works fine out of box for me. Is keyboard focus at text editor?

Comment: Works on my machine. I have no problem changing zoom using Ctrl+MouseWheel Up/Down in editor views.

Comment: Working fine here...try using the other CTRL key.

Comment: may have to investigate if any extension is interferring

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An extension actually disabled the OOB behavior : [Tweaks for Visual Studio](https://github.com/madskristensen/Tweakster#disablezoom).

Disabling it solved the issue.

Also possible to specify this behavior in the extension settings.

Comment: Remark: The extension setting takes effect only after closing all instances of VS and opening it again.